# PHP / MySQL - Count how many table in database contain Specific name

Tags: mysql, database

I'm building an admin to control an interactive game, and I'm using PHP/MySql to store all the data for all the rounds. Each of the tables that I want to load into the game via PHP are titled "Puzzle*" with the * being an incremental index number. There are a few other tables in my database for global game data and bonus rounds.

What I want to be able to do is count the number of tables in my database that contain the name "Puzzle", and then use that total number as a randomizer to select a puzzle randomly. I plan to have roughly 50 puzzles, so an automated way of selecting a random puzzle, and then if I want to select another puzzle - to remove that previous puzzle from the list so that there is no chance of it being repeated until I start the whole game over again.

**MySQL Database**

```
Database Name: puzzleGame
Table 1: puzzle1
Table 2: puzzle2
Table 3: puzzle3
Table 4: puzzle4
Table 5: globals
Table 6: bonus
```

Comment: If this is just about querying PHP is not related. This also looks like a bad DB design. Why not have `puzzles` and autoincrement and `id` column, or have some other reference that associates each puzzle.

Comment: these are just the names of the tables inside the database, not the contents of the tables - since most of the tables will be named the same, I figured it would be handy to just return a count of all of the tables that contained the word "puzzle" in their name.

How is this "bad" table design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just run a [`SHOW TABLES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-tables.html) query e.g.

```
SHOW TABLES FROM puzzleGame LIKE 'puzzle%'
```

Then in your PHP you could load them all into an array and deal with the random selection.

Answer (score 1):

Try mysql query:

```
show tables from your_db like '%puzzle%';
```

and then count result

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP. But I know this MySql query will give your result :

**SELECT TABLE_NAME from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA='puzzleGame' and TABLE_TYPE='base table' and TABLE_NAME like 'Puzzle%';**